# How to check from terminal if any GUI installed in UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu

I'm looking for command to check from terminal, is any GUI installed to my UBUNTU.
I couldn't find any satisfying answer

Comment: Do you want to know if a GUI ist running or if it is installed (but not necessary running)?

Comment: Please define "GUI".

Answer (score 13):

```
dpkg -l|grep xserver
```

will tell you if X11 (core system for most GUIs) is installed. To check if any  desktops are installed, you will have to guess, as there are just too many. Try something like:

```
dpkg -l|egrep -i "(kde|gnome|lxde|xfce|mint|unity|fluxbox|openbox)" | grep -v library
```

Comment: And there is still the possibility that someone installed a windows manager/desktop environment without using packages.

Comment: This will also return a false positive if the X server *was* installed and then removed. And if the X server was installed by hand (or another package system), it will return false. You could use something like `which Xorg`, but that's also not 100% sure.

Comment: Are there really "too many"?

Answer (score 7):

There are many parts in a GUI, and it's possible that some part would be installed but some other parts would be missing.

Displaying a GUI locally (as opposed to running GUI programs over the network, displaying them remotely) requires an X server. So if you want to know whether a local GUI is installed, test for the presence of an X server. The X server for local display is `Xorg`.

```
type Xorg
```

will tell you whether it's installed. It won't tell you whether it's working or running, those would be different questions altogether.

(Recent versions of Ubuntu have introduced a new GUI, [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_(software)), but X should still be available.)

Comment: It does not depends on package manager and still very realiable to uninstalls! Superb, very realiable way!

Answer (score 7):

Type this command:

```
ls /usr/bin/*session
```

Based on what you see on the screen you can find out what GUI you are using right now. For example you are:

- in GNOME if it returns `/usr/bin/gnome-session` (and more);
- in MATE if it returns `/usr/bin/mate-session` (and more);
- in LXDE if it returns `/usr/bin/lxsession` (and more);
- in JWM if it returns `/usr/bin/icewm-session` (should be `jwm-session`, not?!).